# Internal user or community user for partners?

Tags: partner-communities, partner

In the current project I am working on, I found that client has created internal users for partner and any partner can directly login to salesforce org and has access to almost every object and data.

Is it a correct approach to create Internal users for partners? Instead there must be a Partner community for partners and partners should be allowed to access data only through community?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a best way to open up a partner to internal salesforce org. I would prefer salesforce community:

1. They will consume salesforce license which is costly and partner community login license is cheaper.
2. Data security - by making it only relevant data available in community.
3. A customized company oriented user experience and theme using community - Mobile Friendly.
4. Easy multi-lingual translation.